# DB2 Query to fetch multiple row value in a single field

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have tables lets say:

```
**Master Table**
ID, MasterID, Info,   Date
1,  'B101',    'ABC',  12-01-15

**Detail Table**
ID, MasterID, Code
1,  'B101',   '20'
2,  'B101',   '50'
3,  'B101',   'x'
4,  'B101',   'y'
```

I want the result set to be:

```
MasterID, BankCodes, Date
'B101',   20-50-x-y,    12-01-15
```

I am working in db2.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of db2 you might be able to do:

```
with details(masterid, code) as ( values ('B101',20),('B101',50) ) 
select masterid, listagg(code,'-') 
from details 
group by masterid

B101     20-50
```

You can specify an order for code by:

```
listagg(code,'-') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY code)
```

Comment: I have to fetch fields from master table as well. queries will inner join will work. but how?

Comment: Listagg works just like any other aggregate function. I suggest that you try try extending my example with a join and see where that leads you.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`, concatenate min code '-' max code:

```
select mt.MasterID,
       cast(min(dt.code) as varchar(11)) || '-' || cast(max(dt.code) as varchar(11)) as BankCodes,
       mt.date
from MasterTable mt
    left join DetailTable dt on mt.MasterID = dt.MasterID
group by mt.MasterID, mt.date
```

`LEFT JOIN` is to also return MasterId's without any details. If that's not needed, just do `INNER JOIN` instead.

**Edit:** Or did I get something wrong here? What's the expected result if there are 3 different code for a masterid?

Comment: I have to use inner join between master and detail tables. I have to fetch other data as well in the same query. You are only quering detail table.
Check updated question.

Comment: @waleedansari, and what's the expected result if there are more than 2 codes for a masterid? Can't you add another row (3,  'B101',   30) to the Detail Table?

Comment: Jarl, db2 uses `||` for concatenation

Comment: @jarlh your code works well when there are two codes only. I have more than two code.

Comment: @waleedansari, you never told us the expected result if there are more that 2 codes. You want them all?